# TRichEdit and the encoding of Unicode characters in RTF

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, rtf, delphi-11-alexandria, trichedit

In Delphi 11.1.5, is there a way to make `TRichEdit.Lines.SaveToStream()` encode Unicode characters in `\uXXXX` format instead of `\'XX` in the generated RTF?

I have to interpret the returned RTF content, and I can't enforce the charset value set at the `\fXX` font (I can only do something with the `ansicpg` value). However, if the codes are in `\uXXXX` format, I can easily generate my Unicode string.

Or, if there is no trick, how can I enforce the charset values when generating `ansicpg` encoded ANSI char from `\'XX` code?

I use `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` API calls to convert texts between codepages.

Comment: The code page in RTF can be set in the font definition (see https://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading14) so in order to know the code page of any specific \'xx your code needs to find out which font definition is currently used. The only 'trick' I can imagine is to enforce that all font definitions use only one fixed code page. Every \'xx then could be easily interpreted.